# What is the probability for 2 points on a sphere to be in the same hemisphere, given the angle between them?

Tags: probability, geometry

The sphere has predefined hemispheres, and 2 points are randomly selected.

If the 2 points are 180 degrees apart, we know they are not in the same hemisphere. if it's only 1 degree it probably is in the same half.

How do I calculate the probability for angle X?

Comment: One slight simplification: The probability for them both to be in the upper hemisphere should be the same as to find them both in the lower hemisphere, and thus half the probability to find them in the same hemisphere. So you might as well just consider the case of both in the upper hemisphere.

Comment: Also, I think the following question is equivalent to yours: Pick a point on the sphere and a random plane through the origin. What is the probability that both chosen point and the North Pole lie on the same side of the plane?

Comment: @Semiclassical, Your simplification sound good. how would you use the angle in the equivalent question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These spherical trigonometry problems can be hard on the brain. But in this case the answer is surprisingly simple. You ask:

> Given a partition of the sphere into two hemispheres, what is the
>   probability that two random points separated by an angle $X$ lie in the same
>   hemisphere?

We can turn this problem inside out, and ask:

> Given two points separated by an angle $X$, what is the probability
>   that a random partition of the sphere into two hemispheres will result
>   in the two points lying in the same hemisphere?

So let us take two points on the equator, with coordinates $A=(0,0)$ (see [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island)) and $(0,X)$, where $X\le 180$. Any point $P$ on the sphere defines a partition into two hemispheres, by considering that point as a pole. We may assume that the longitude $\theta$ of $P$ is in the range $[90^\circ,270^\circ]$, because if not, we can replace $P$ by its antipodal point. And for such a point $P=(\theta,\phi)$ to separate the points $A$ and $B$ into distinct hemispheres requires $90^\circ\le\theta\le X+90^\circ$. The probability of this is clearly $X/180$.

Hence the answer to your question is $1-X/180$.

Comment: I feel like this should be obvious, but what would the probability be if one asks that the angle be _at most_ $X$? I had managed to convince myself that it should be $$\frac{1}{X}\int_0^X (1-X'/180)\,dX'=1-X/360.$$ This agrees with the cases of $X=0$ (same point, so always same hemisphere) and $X\leq 180$ (antipodes, so never same hemisphere). But when I've tested $X\leq 90$ numerically, I don't seem to get the correct statistics.

Comment: @Semiclassical: it depends crucially on how you sample the points. Are you choosing the angle of separation from a uniform distribution on $[0,X]$? Or are you choosing two points at random, and rejecting those pairs whose angle of separation is $>X$? You will get two different answers!

Comment: Good point. I was doing the latter method when generating variates, but I guess my formula above assumes the former method? (Presumably, then, the two coincide in the edge cases but not in between.)